# Timeago jquery Plugin Timezone

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, timeago

I am developing an asp.net application in which I am using [`timeago`](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin of jQuery and I am facing the fact that I am getting the time in UTC whenever my local time is GMT + 5.00 and on the server side I am getting the UTC time.

So now the question is this how to convert UTC to GMT+5.00, If I am getting the time right now then It is giving me the output 5 hours ago which shows that the output is in GMT.

I know this question is repeating but I am unable to understand the previously 
discussed question.

The code of the plugin is given below:

```
(function ($) {
    $.timeago = function (timestamp) {
        if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
            return inWords(timestamp);
        } else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
            return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
        } else if (typeof timestamp === "number") {
            return inWords(new Date(timestamp));
        } else {
            return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
        }
    };
    var $t = $.timeago;

    $.extend($.timeago, {
        settings: {
            refreshMillis: 60000,
            allowFuture: false,
            strings: {
                prefixAgo: null,
                prefixFromNow: null,
                suffixAgo: "ago",
                suffixFromNow: "from now",
                seconds: "less than a minute",
                //minute: "about a minute",
                minute: "a minute",
                minutes: "%d minutes",
                //hour: "about an hour",
                hour: "an hour",
                //hours: "about %d hours",
                hours: "%d hours",
                day: "a day",
                days: "%d days",
                //month: "about a month",
                month: "a month",
                months: "%d months",
                //year: "about a year",
                year: "a year",
                years: "%d years",
                wordSeparator: " ",
                numbers: []
            }
        },
        inWords: function (distanceMillis) {
            var $l = this.settings.strings;
            var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
            var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
            if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
                if (distanceMillis < 0) {
                    prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
                    suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
                }
            }

            var seconds = Math.abs(distanceMillis) / 1000;
            var minutes = seconds / 60;
            var hours = minutes / 60;
            var days = hours / 24;
            var years = days / 365;

            function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
                var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
                var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
                return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
            }

            var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
        seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
        minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
        minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
        hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
        hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
        days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
        days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
        days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
        years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
        substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));

            var separator = $l.wordSeparator === undefined ? " " : $l.wordSeparator;
            return $.trim([prefix, words, suffix].join(separator));
        },
        parse: function (iso8601) {
            var s = $.trim(iso8601);
            s = s.replace(/\.\d+/, ""); // remove milliseconds
            s = s.replace(/-/, "/").replace(/-/, "/");
            s = s.replace(/T/, " ").replace(/Z/, " UTC");
            s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/, " $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
            return new Date(s);
        },
        datetime: function (elem) {
            var iso8601 = $t.isTime(elem) ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
            return $t.parse(iso8601);
        },
        isTime: function (elem) {
            // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
            return $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
        }
    });

    $.fn.timeago = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.each(refresh);

        var $s = $t.settings;
        if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
            setInterval(function () { self.each(refresh); }, $s.refreshMillis);
        }
        return self;
    };

    function refresh() {
        var data = prepareData(this);
        if (!isNaN(data.datetime)) {
            $(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
        }
        return this;
    }

    function prepareData(element) {
        element = $(element);
        if (!element.data("timeago")) {
            element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
            var text = $.trim(element.text());
            if (text.length > 0 && !($t.isTime(element) && element.attr("title"))) {
                element.attr("title", text);
            }
        }
        return element.data("timeago");
    }

    function inWords(date) {
        return $t.inWords(distance(date));
    }

    function distance(date) {
        return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
    }

    // fix for IE6 suckage
    document.createElement("abbr");
    document.createElement("time");
 (jQuery));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it server-side you want to "convert" from UTC to GMT+5 ? Or client-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.com/livestampjs) with something like this:

`date` is the `DateTime` object you are trying to output.

```
<span data-livestamp="<%= (date - new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0)).TotalSeconds) %>">
</span>
```

You are outputting the Unix timestamp, which is always in UTC, so it doesn't matter what timezone the user's computer is in. It will always print out the correct "timeago" text.